# Referencing Databases In SQL 2008 Mirrored Reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 2 databases.

1 is a mirror of the other, **EXCEPT**, 1 has a table called **DOG** and the other has the same table but it is called **DOG2**.

I have an ssrs report that references DOG..DOGID.

Now when DOG goes down I want to use the connection string to DOG2, the only issue is my reference to DOG..ID will no longer be valid if I am connecting to DOG2.

Is there a way in SQL code to make it so if DOG..DOGID is invalid use DOG2..DOGID?

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be to have a synonym DOG that points to DOG2 in your second database:

```
create synonym DOG for DOG2;
```

so DOG..id is always valid.